# I ran a jar file using Java fx on raspberrypi3, but the background image gif is not output

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi3

The background image is normally output on the desktop, but it is not output on the raspberry pie.

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage)throws IOException {
    Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("prototype.fxml"));

    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.setTitle("Prototype");
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }
}
```

Here is the code for my Javafx Controller.java

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{
    @FXML private StackPane background;

    File five=new File("/home/pi/Desktop/image/snow.gif");

    private Image snow=new Image(five.toURI().toString());

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    Platform.runLater(()->{
                        BackgroundImage e=new BackgroundImage(snow,BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER,new BackgroundSize(BackgroundSize.AUTO, BackgroundSize.AUTO, true, true, true, true));
                        background.setBackground(new Background(e));
                    });
                    try {Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                }
            };
        };
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    };
```

}

And this is xml written by a scene builder.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<StackPane fx:id="background" maxHeight="500.0" maxWidth="1000.0" minHeight="250.0" minWidth="500.0" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <GridPane alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="250.0" maxWidth="300.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefHeight="254.0" prefWidth="276.0" rotate="180.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff; -fx-background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); -fx-background-radius: 50;" StackPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="watch" alignment="CENTER" style="-fx-font-size: 60;" text="Time" />
            <Label fx:id="weeken" style="-fx-font-size: 30;" text="Week" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label fx:id="weathering" style="-fx-font-size: 30;" text="Weathing" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rotationAxis>
            <Point3D y="1.0" />
         </rotationAxis>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

It’s part of the original program. I need to convert weather data into a gif background image. But the image is not output. I want help.

Comment: It looks like you have 3D requirements? Those are not supported on the RaspberryPi.

Comment: You mean it's impossible?

Comment: Impossible is a strong word. So far JavaFX 3D is not supported on the Raspberry Pi. But adding support is not so easy. Maybe you can find another approach instead of using those rotations.

Comment: So can I use mp4 instead of gif image?

Comment: Not all distributions of JavaFX for ARM support media. If you are running on Java 8 this [one](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/javafxports/get/) does.